# Clipboard - Electron.js get file properties

Tags: javascript, typescript, electron

I created app with electron.js and used clipboard electron.
Question is so:

When I copied any file (example: image, txt, file, video ..) and after paste it -
I want to get all information: as `<input type="file" />` returned (name, size, path ....)
I did not found any example like this as I want
For example I copied image this code returned path of file -

```
let rawFilePath = clipboard.read('FileNameW');


 let filePath = rawFilePath.replace(new RegExp(String.fromCharCode(0), 'g'), '');

console.log('file path', filePath);
```

Has any way to get all information as I said ? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: So what information do you have? Do you only have the path of the copied file?

Comment: I got only path now but I need to other information too about this file

Comment: [ksh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4277402) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66470117) saying "As you have got the file path, you can read the file info use Node.js fs module.See this https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_stats"